# Is tangent monotonically increasing?

Tags: functions

According to wolfram [a function is monotonic if its derivative never changes sign, but the derivative doesn't have to be continuous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicFunction.html). So I feel the answer is Yes, tangent is monotonically increasing. Maybe not?

Comment: I would say not. On any interval over which it is defined, it is increasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any function defined from $\Bbb R$ (the set of real numbers) to $\Bbb R$ is monotonic iff its derivative never changes sign, yes. But $\tan(x)$ is *not* a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, since it's not defined on all real numbers.

In fact, the thing about derivatives is only true when the domain is a connected set (i.e. an interval)! (Remember that $\Bbb R=(-\infty,\infty)$ and is thus an interval.)

The domain of $\tan(x)$ is:
$$\left\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ne k\pi+\frac\pi2\right\}$$
This is not an interval! Therefore, the theorem linking derivatives to monotonicity does not hold.

In fact, $\tan(x)$ is *not* monotonic. To see this, note that:
$$\frac\pi3<\frac{2\pi}3$$
but:
$$\tan\Big(\frac\pi3\Big)>\tan\Big(\frac{2\pi}3\Big)$$
(The former is $\sqrt3$; the latter is $-\sqrt3$.)

However, $\tan(x)$ is monotonic over the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. And it is monotonic over any interval on which it's defined. But it's not monotonic over its entire domain.